# Validate before creating objects and create multiple models data through one serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I created multiple models related to an applicant

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    app_no = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

class ApplicantBasicDetails(models.Model):
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(Applicant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    m_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)

class AppplcantFamilyDetails(models.Model):
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(Applicant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    relation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    m_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now developing an API where someone will POST below body

```
{
    "app_no": "123456",
    "applicant_basic_details": {
        "f_name": "",
        "m_name": "",
        "l_name": "",
        "gender": ""
    },
    "applicant_family_datails": [
        {    
            "relation": "",
            "f_name": "",
            "m_name": "",
            "l_name": "",
            "gender": ""
        },
        {
            "relation": "",
            "f_name": "",
            "m_name": "",
            "l_name": "",
            "gender": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't have much idea how to validate multiple models data first before creating objects I wrote one serializer.

```
class AllInOneSer(serializers.Serializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        app_no = validated_data.pop("app_no")
        app_ser = ApplicantSer(data={"app_no": app_no})
        if app_ser.is_valid():
            pass
        else:
            return "error", app_ser.errors
```

How can I pass these multiple models data through one serializer, to validate and create objects?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I wrote the below procedure to handle multiple models in one serializer.
this is not a full and structured code. but sufficient to understand how can we handle multiple models, In my real project I combined more than 30 models into one serializer and did many code optimization by loop and eval statement for repeating tasks like repeatedly passing data into serializer and so on.

```
class AllInOneSer(serializers.Serializer):
    data = serializers.JSONField()

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return {"data": data}

    def validate(self, attrs):
        print("->>>--------------> validate: ")

        type, errors = self.all_data_check_or_save(data=attrs["data"], flag=0)
        if type == "error":
            raise ValidationError(errors)
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("->>>--------------> save: ")
        type, errors = self.all_data_check_or_save(data=validated_data["data"], flag=1)
        return errors


    def all_data_check_or_save(self, data, flag=0):

        errors = {}
        status = "success"
        app_no = data["app_no"]
        
        if flag:
            basic_details = dict(data["applicant_basic_details"], **{"applicant": app_no})
            family_datails = dict(data["applicant_family_datails"], **{"applicant": app_no})

        basic_details = data["applicant_basic_details"]
        family_datails = data["applicant_family_datails"]

        app_ser = ApplicantSer(data={"app_no": app_no})
        status1, errors["app_data"] = self.validation_or_save_res(app_ser, flag)

        basic_ser = ApplicantBasicDetailsSer(data=basic_details)
        status2, errors["applicant_basic_details"] = self.validation_or_save_res(basic_ser, flag)

        family_ser = AppplcantFamilyDetailsSer(data=family_datails)
        status3, errors["applicant_family_datails"] = self.validation_or_save_res(family_ser, flag)

        if "error" in [status1, status2, status3]:
            status = "error"

        return status, errors  


    def validation_or_save_res(self, serializer, flag=0):
        if serializer.is_valid():
            if flag:
                serializer.save()
        else:
            return "error", serializer.errors, extra_data

        return "success", {}
```